# Proper usage of Django Mixins

Tags: python, django, mixins

So i just started porting my old code to Class Based Views, and i am still new at that. My question is related to Django mixins, where i have a mixin that i am going to use in various classes to validate some information. The problem is that i don't know how to access the information it returns without getting 500 internal error.

```
class CheckTokenMixin(object):
    def request_token(self,request):
        params = {'username':settings.OAUTH_USERNAME,'password':hashlib.sha256(settings.OAUTH_PASSWORD).hexdigest()}
        req = Request(settings.REMOTE_SERVER+'oauth', urllib.urlencode(params))
        return json.loads(urlopen(req).read())

    def get_valid_token(self):
        if datetime.datetime.now() > request.session['access_token'].creation_date + datetime.timedelta(days=1):
            temp = self.request_token(request)
            tokenobj = AccessToken.objects.all()[:1].get()
            tokenobj.access_token = temp['token']
            tokenobj.creation_date = datetime.datetime.now()
            tokenobj.save()
            request.session['access_token'] = tokenobj

        return request.session['access_token']

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ctx = super(CheckTokenMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ctx['access_token'] = self.get_valid_token()
        return ctx

class RateAppView(LoginRequiredMixin, JSONResponseMixin, AjaxResponseMixin, CheckTokenMixin, View):

    @method_decorator(csrf_protect)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(RateAppView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def post_ajax(self, request, username):
        u = get_object_or_404(User, pk=current_user_id(request))
        city_obj = City.objects.get(id=request.POST.get('city_id', None))
        x = self.get_valid_token
        print "teste: " , x.access_token
        print "teste2: " , self.get_context_data.['access_token'].access_token
```

i want something like

> self.get_valid_token

or

> self.get_context_data.['access_token'].access_token

to access the data from my mixin, how do i do it the proper way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`self.get_valid_token()` would be correct. However, you have several errors in that method, which are no doubt what is causing the problem: in particular, you refer to `request` without defining it at any point. I expect you mean `self.request` instead.